# Load file data from local xml file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, jwplayer6

Is possible to load data from local xml file?

Here is my code:

```
var file;
jwplayer().onError(function() {
    jwplayer().load({
        file: file
    });
    jwplayer().play();
    jwplayer().onComplete(function() {
        if (doesConnectionExist()) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

The var file must be load from a xml file that contains http://localhost/error.mp4.

What should I use to do that?

Because each client may have a different location error file.

Comment: So this is a PHP file (assuming since it's tagged PHP)? If so you can use simplexml to find the error file dynamically on the server side - based on the XML file, then echo it to the JavaScript before sending back the response - var file = '<?php echo $errFile ?>';

Comment: Yes is php. I have a working solution, with     var file = "http://localhost/error.mp4";     , but if the client have a different folder inside localhost no error file will be played. that's why I need to load it from a local config file, but how do I do it?